# AS3 - Should I add all objects to the stage, or just the one's on screen?

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, air, stage, displayobject

In actionscript3 (cs5.5 or flashdevelop), what is the best practice for managing off-screen display objects?

**Option A**: While loading the level, place all objects on the stage (even the ones way waaay offscreen)

or

**Option B**: Keep track of which objects should be on screen, adding them to the screen when they should be there, and removing them when they shouldn't.

---

*Option A* is definitely far easier to manage, but which is actually the more performant of the two options?  Is one better in certain scenarios? 
(ie. a tile map may benefit from managing which tiles are on screen (especially for huge maps), but perhaps flash takes care of all this behind the scenes?)

Answer (score 1):

Option B is going to be a lot faster, most of the time. But for tile maps and similar, I would recommend avoiding the scene-graph and use manual bitmapdata-blitting instead.